# iFrame Javascript Across Subdomain

Tags: javascript, iframe, subdomain

I know this is a duplicate question however my requirements are slightly different,

In a previous question this was tackled by setting:

```
document.domain = "yourdomain.com";
```

on both pages.

However... I have a www.example.com domain and I have a mail.example.com

the mail.example.com is a subdomain I have no access to, it is automatically generated by my shared hosting and its where i access my emails. However I want an iframe with mail.example.com as the source on one of my pages.

e.g.

```
// www.example.com/mail.php
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
       ...
       <? include("header.php"); ?>
       ...
       <iframe src="mail.example.com"></iframe>
       ...
    </body>
</html>
```

This works as expected but certain styles are applied to the iframe, so i want to use javascript to remove all the styles, then add my own.

But because i dont have access to mail.example.com, i cant set `document.domain = "example.com";` in the sub domain.

Is there another way round this?

**EDIT**

I didn't make it very clear what I had already tried.

This is my exact iframe code in my mail.php page on the www.example.com domain:

```
<iframe id="mail" src="http://mail.a3mediauk.co.uk/mail2/source/index.php" height="800" width="960"></iframe>
```

This is the javascript code thats at the very top of the head element in the mail.php page:

```
document.domain = "http://mail.a3mediauk.co.uk";
```

And this is the jquery code im trying to use to remove the style:

```
$(function(){
    $("iframe#mail").load(function(){
        $("iframe#mail body").removeAttr("bgcolor");
    });
});
```

if its any help, the document.domain throws this error in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot the `http://`
An iFrame is client-sided (HTML) so you have to enter the absolute path because it is a different domain. What you have written would redirect to `http://yourdomain.com/mail.yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the same origin policy is concerned, the URLs have to match exactly. It doesn't matter if one is a subdomain of the other; the strings are different, so you're violating the policy.

I don't see a good solution. If the page was simple (no or only simple JavaScript, no links, etc), you can try to fetch the mail page with JavaScript into a String, strip the header (i.e. convert the `body` into a `div`) and then add that to your main page. But of course, this would break all links, the referrer, and cause lots of other problems like, say, what happens if a new version of the mail interface is installed?

Another solution would be to install a proxy service which makes everything from `mail.domain.com` available as `your.domain.com/mail`. If you run Apache on your domain, a simple rewrite rule using [the "Proxy Throughput" feature](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) should do the trick.

Comment: Just to clarify, `document.domain` allows you to do x-domain on pages from different subdomains, but its value on both pages has to be the common root domain with no subdomains specified. Since OP can't specify `document.domain` in the iframed page, proxy seems to me to be the best solution.